# Trouble with TypeScript typing for store enhancers in redux 4.0

Tags: typescript, redux

Can some TypeScript master help me figure out why this code to create store enhancers in redux 4.0 is giving me type errors?

The minimal repo is [here](https://github.com/huy-nguyen/redux-enhancer-type-problem). It's creating a do-nothing store ehnahcer. After cloning, install dependencies by running `yarn`. To see the error, run `yarn run compile`.

The relevant file is

```js
import {
  StoreEnhancer,
  StoreEnhancerStoreCreator,
  Reducer,
  DeepPartial,
  AnyAction,
} from 'redux';

interface RootState {
  someKey: string;
}

export const enhancer: StoreEnhancer =
  (createStore: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator): StoreEnhancerStoreCreator =>
    (reducer: Reducer<RootState, AnyAction>, preloadedState?: DeepPartial<RootState>) => {

  const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState);
  const newDispatch: typeof store.dispatch = <A extends AnyAction>(action: A) => {
    const result = store.dispatch(action);
    return result;
  }
  return {
    ...store,
    dispatch: newDispatch,
  };
};
```

The error I'm getting is

```something
src/enhancer.ts(15,5): error TS2322: Type '(reducer: Reducer<RootState, AnyAction>, preloadedState?: DeepPartial<RootState> | undefined) => ...' is not assignable to type 'StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<{}, {}>'.
  Types of parameters 'reducer' and 'reducer' are incompatible.
    Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
      Type 'RootState | undefined' is not assignable to type 'S | undefined'.
        Type 'RootState' is not assignable to type 'S | undefined'.
          Type 'RootState' is not assignable to type 'S'.
```

I don't understand why `RootState` is not assignable to `S`.

Comment: I believe this question is answered by [How do I relate the generic types defined between higher-order functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53353422/155423). I had what appears to the same problem.

Comment: Hi, Have you solved this issue? Can you share the solution if yes? Thank you.

Comment: @Anatoly it will be better if you show your own code. there must be some difference

Comment: @AabirHussain, the internal implementation was different, but the function signature was the same. Anyway, I solved this issue by using middleware and for me, it isn't actual. But will be happy to grant this bounty to someone, sure not only me had same issue.

Comment: Ok @Anatoly m gonna post an answer but please edit my answer in order to show your solution and also I will wait for the  bounty. Thanks in advance dude.

Answer (score 5):

Lets deep dive at how `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` is defined

```
export type StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext = {}, StateExt = {}> = <S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction>(reducer: Reducer<S, A>, preloadedState?: DeepPartial<S>) => Store<S & StateExt, A> & Ext;
```

This is generic type with two type arguments, `Ext` and `StateExt`. The result of this type is *another generic* function. For example if we do

```
const genericStoreCreator: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator = <S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction>(r: Reducer<S, A>) => createStore(r)
```

`genericStoreCreator` will still be *generic* function. We already used generic type `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` without providing type arguments to it (with default type values), but result is still generic function.

Then we may call `genericStoreCreator` providing specific type arguments for `S` and `A`.

```
const store = genericStoreCreator((state: RootState = { someKey: 'someKey' }, action: AnyAction) => state)
```

And now we have specific `store` without any generics.

You may consider `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` as generic inside generic.

Now lets get back to store enhancers. From [source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/87eee1e879a7ecbdab32caa09dfa2bfc566d6269/src/types/store.ts#L238) (didn't find it in documentation)

> A store enhancer is a higher-order function that composes a store creator to return a new, enhanced store creator.

So result of store enhancer should still be generic store creator. Inside enhancer function we shouldn't relate on specific shape of state (i.e. it have `someKey` property) or specific shape of action (except it has `type` property). When implementing enhancer we don't know what exact store it will enhance.

To make your code working, just carry generics inside enhancer code

```
export const enhancer: StoreEnhancer =
  (createStore: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator): StoreEnhancerStoreCreator =>
    <S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction>(reducer: Reducer<S, A>, preloadedState?: DeepPartial<RootState>) => {

  const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState);
  const newDispatch: Dispatch<A> = (action) => {
    const result = store.dispatch(action);
    return result;
  }
  return {
    ...store,
    dispatch: newDispatch,
   };
};
```

Take a note that enhanced store creator is still generic and can be user with any state and actions.

But what can we enhance with enhancer? As [source says](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/87eee1e879a7ecbdab32caa09dfa2bfc566d6269/src/types/store.ts#L256)

> @template Ext Store extension that is mixed into the Store type.
>
> @template StateExt State extension that is mixed into the state type.

Lets extend store with `print5` function which when called will log 5 to console.

```
export const enhancer: StoreEnhancer<{ print5: () => void }> =
  (createStore: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator): StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<{ print5: () => void }> =>
    <S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction>(reducer: Reducer<S, A>, preloadedState?: DeepPartial<RootState>) => {

  const store = createStore(reducer, preloadedState);
  const newDispatch: Dispatch<A> = (action) => {
    const result = store.dispatch(action);
    return result;
  }
  return {
    ...store,
    dispatch: newDispatch,
    print5 () { console.log(5) },
   };
  };
```

Again take a note that resulting store is still generic.

And here is simple [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-store-enhancer-eh4vt). Take a note how `print5` function is propagated from enhancer to resulting store.