# How do I relate the generic types defined between higher-order functions?

Tags: typescript, generics, higher-order-functions

I am creating a Redux store enhancer that takes in a function to serialize the Redux state. I'll construct the store and set up a subscription for changes — on each change, I'll serialize the state. For this MCVE, I'm ignoring the subscription aspect and just immediately calling the serialization function.

However, due to the higher-order nature of the function, I'm unable to correlate my generic type for the state (needed for the serialization function) with the generic type returned by the store creator:

```
// Copied and reduced from Redux 4.0.1

type Reducer<S = any> = (
  state: S | undefined,
) => S

type DeepPartial<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]> }

interface Store<S = any> {
  getState(): S
}

type StoreEnhancer<Ext = {}, StateExt = {}> = (
  next: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator
) => StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext, StateExt>

type StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<Ext = {}, StateExt = {}> = <
  S = any,
>(
  reducer: Reducer<S>,
  preloadedState?: DeepPartial<S>
) => Store<S & StateExt> & Ext

// My reduced code

interface Config<S> {
  serialize: (state: S) => string;
}

const storage = <S>(config: Config<S>): StoreEnhancer => createStore => (reducer, preloadedState) => {
  const { serialize } = config;

  const theStore = createStore(reducer, preloadedState);

  const state = theStore.getState();
  const serializedState = serialize(state);

  return theStore;
}
```

([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Copied%20and%20reduced%20from%20Redux%204.0.1%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Reducer%3CS%20%3D%20any%3E%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20state%3A%20S%20%7C%20undefined%2C%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20S%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20DeepPartial%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3F%3A%20DeepPartial%3CT%5BK%5D%3E%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Store%3CS%20%3D%20any%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20getState()%3A%20S%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20StoreEnhancer%3CExt%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20StateExt%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20(%0D%0A%20%20next%3A%20StoreEnhancerStoreCreator%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20StoreEnhancerStoreCreator%3CExt%2C%20StateExt%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20StoreEnhancerStoreCreator%3CExt%20%3D%20%7B%7D%2C%20StateExt%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3E%20%3D%20%3C%0D%0A%20%20S%20%3D%20any%2C%0D%0A%3E(%0D%0A%20%20reducer%3A%20Reducer%3CS%3E%2C%0D%0A%20%20preloadedState%3F%3A%20DeepPartial%3CS%3E%0D%0A)%20%3D%3E%20Store%3CS%20%26%20StateExt%3E%20%26%20Ext%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20My%20Code%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Config%3CS%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20serialize%3A%20(state%3A%20S)%20%3D%3E%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20storage%20%3D%20%3CS%3E(config%3A%20Config%3CS%3E)%3A%20StoreEnhancer%20%3D%3E%20createStore%20%3D%3E%20(reducer%2C%20preloadedState)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20%7B%20serialize%20%7D%20%3D%20config%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20theStore%20%3D%20createStore(reducer%2C%20preloadedState)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20state%20%3D%20theStore.getState()%3B%0D%0A%20%20const%20serializedState%20%3D%20serialize(state)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20theStore%3B%0D%0A%7D))

The error is:

```
const serializedState = serialize(state);
                                  ^~~~~

Argument of type 'S & {}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'S'.
```

The error message is annoying because I'm pretty sure that the two `S` are unrelated; changing the definition in `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` to use `X` instead of `S` changes this error message.

How can I connect my generic type parameter with the generic parameter defined on `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the problem identified by @matt-mccutchen. `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` is a generic function, so `(reducer, preloadedState) => {` is a generic function with an `S` generic type argument, this is why the compiler reports the incompatibility between the two `S` types.

The solution I would propose would be  for `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` to not be generic, from what I can tell the reducer and the payload should have the same generic type argument as the `Config`. This solution requires adding an extra type parameter to `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` and `StoreEnhancer`:

```
type Reducer<S = any> = (
  state: S | undefined,
) => S

type DeepPartial<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[K]> }

interface Store<S = any> {
  getState(): S
}

type StoreEnhancer<S, Ext = {}, StateExt = {}> = (
  next: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<S>
) => StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<S, Ext, StateExt>

type StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<S, Ext = {}, StateExt = {}> = (
  reducer: Reducer<S>,
  preloadedState?: DeepPartial<S>
) => Store<S> & Ext

// My Code

interface Config<S> {
  serialize: (state: S) => string;
}

const storage = <S>(config: Config<S>): StoreEnhancer<S> => createStore => (reducer, preloadedState) => {
  const { serialize } = config;

  const theStore = createStore(reducer, preloadedState);

  const state = theStore.getState();
  const serializedState = serialize(state);

  return theStore;
}
```

Comment: Since this would require changes to the Redux code, what kinds of backwards compatibility hazards would this entail?

Comment: @Shepmaster I missed that that part of the code was part of Redux .. that will probably not work ..you could try  copying the definitions an modifying them .. not sure what the larger context is.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `storage` is declared to (indirectly, via `StoreEnhancer`) return a `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator`, which is a generic function that must work for all `S`.  However, a given call to `storage` produces a store creator that works for only one `S`: the `S` of the `config` that was passed.

It seems to me that the only way you could produce a `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` would be if you started with a `serialize` function that itself was generic in `S`.  I'm not sure if that makes sense in your scenario.  Maybe someone familiar with Redux would have a better idea of what to do.

Comment: *a `serialize` function that itself was generic in `S`* — this seems unlikely to work because then I wouldn't have any knowledge about the contents of the state in order to serialize it.

Answer (score 0):

[Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53356386/155423) put me on the right track:

> This solution requires adding an extra type parameter to `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` and `StoreEnhancer`

However, the appropriate type parameter already existed; I just wasn't understanding how to use it correctly. Specifically, a `StoreEnhancer` returns a `StoreEnhancerStoreCreator` with the default type parameters. If I instead set the type parameters, I now know what kind of state will be returned:

```
const storage = <S>(config: Config<S>): StoreEnhancer =>
  (createStore: StoreEnhancerStoreCreator<{}, S>) =>
  //            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ set this type
    (reducer, preloadedState) => {
```